# Facing issue with sorting when documents saves only non-null columns

Tags: mongodb, sorting, nosql

Facing issue with sorting when documents saves only non-null columns into documents:
my mongodb document looks like :

```
 # documents-1 :
            "taskId": "2",
            "taskType": "RFOUTAUD",
            "id": "5d25bdda2f7ef0000654f281",             
            "releaseDatetime": "2019-05-28T09:00:39",
            "startDateTime": "2019-05-28T09:44:11",
            "endDateTime": "2019-05-28T09:50:25",
            "resourceId": "SUPER",
            "deviceCode": "QATERM1",
            "effectivePriority": 40,
            "sourceLocation": "1SS100",
            "sourceLocationTravelSequence": "020055000",
            "sourceWorkZone": "1RCVSHP035",
            "sourceWorkZoneTravelSequence": "15035",
```

## documents-2 :

```
        "taskId": "70",
        "taskType": "RFOUTAUD",
        "id": "5d25bdda2f7ef0000654f281",           
        "releaseDatetime": "2019-05-28T09:00:39",
        "startDateTime": "2019-05-28T09:44:11",
        "endDateTime": "2019-05-28T09:50:25",
        "resourceId": "SUPER",
        "deviceCode": "QATERM1",
        "effectivePriority": 40,
        "sourceLocation": "1SS100",
        "sourceLocationTravelSequence": "020055000",
        "sourceWorkZone": "1RCVSHP035",
        "goalTime": 20
```

There are n number of records with  #documents-1: and few records with #documents-2 -has additional column "goalTime"

Now when I m sorting with Pageable on "goalTime" column, In result i get only the documents which has "goalTime" and its excluding the documents where column is missing
the query looks something like this

```
db.getCollection('29ec09db-20b9-4c52-a5af-53519f75a5b4_task').find({}).limit(10).sort({goalTime:1})
```

After going through org.springframework.data.domain.Sort  implementation I found way to include those documents where column itself missing.
Now the issue is the document which has column "goalTime" with value coming as last record and if I put the limit 10 it wont be part of that result.

This is the mongo query :

```
`db.getCollection('29ec09db-20b9-4c52-a5af-53519f75a5b4_task').find({}).limit(2).sort({goalTime:1,NULLS_LAST:1})`
```

I m looking for the result which first shows the document which has sorted columns with value and then documents where the columns itself missing

Comment: Do you have more than 10 records with not nulll goalTime field?

Comment: @ShivamPandey, I think the original question is about how to get the results sorted based on a particular key, followed by the rest of the documents that don't have this key.

Comment: Yes , I'm not saving null values key into mongodb documents

Comment: @Adi are you getting my comment? OP wants to know "Now the issue is the document which has column "goalTime" with value coming as last record and if I put the limit 10 it wont be part of that result." Comment is if there is already more than 10 records present in the database based on the sample query present which have keys or no keys. Let say, "goalTime" is set to "1", set it to "-1" or increase the limit to see the records whatever the use case.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution what I'm looking for. the below query includes records even if sorted columns are not present in documents `db.getCollection('29ec09db-20b9-4c52-a5af-53519f75a5b4_task').find({}).limit(20).sort({goaltime: -1, NULL_LAST : 1})`